# Exception in running "package" phase in Maven pom.xml

Tags: maven

I am new to Maven, so my question might be a little basic. But I am unable to find answers after a lot of searching on the net. I am trying to convert my web project to Maven. I have created all required project folder structures. My POM.xml looks like this:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>gf-undeploy</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>undeploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>clean</phase>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>gf-deploy</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>

    <configuration>
        <glassfishDirectory>${local.glassfish.home}</glassfishDirectory>
        <user>${local.glassfish.user}</user>
        <passwordFile>${local.glassfish.passfile}</passwordFile>
        <autoCreate>true</autoCreate>
        <debug>true</debug>
        <echo>false</echo>
        <terse>true</terse>
        <domain>
            <name>${local.glassfish.domain}</name>
            <adminPort>4848</adminPort>
            <httpPort>8080</httpPort>
            <httpsPort>8181</httpsPort>
            <iiopPort>3700</iiopPort>
            <jmsPort>7676</jmsPort>
            <reuse>false</reuse>
        </domain>
        <components>
            <component>
                <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
                <artifact>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war
                </artifact>
            </component>
        </components>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
     <finalName>final_app</finalName>
</build>
```

I execute the maven command : mvn glassfish:deploy. The application is getting deployed, but I get a 404 status when I try to access the JSPs/servlets. I checked the webapps inside Glassfish directory, the folder structure seems to have got created corrcectly after deployment. Please suggest any solution.

Comment: *The folder structure seems to have got created corrcectly after deployment*. Do you mean "incorrectly?" First step I would just run mvn clean package and check the contents of the generated WAR file.

Comment: The title says you get an exception? What is the stacktrace?